# Entity Framework: am I supposed to modify migration classes?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I hope I understand the basic workflow. First I create a model, then I generate an initial migration, and I generate an SQL from that, OK. I update the model, I create a new migration from that, and a new SQL from that, OK.

Am I correct in assuming that this is a one-way only workflow? If I change the migration class in a bad way, it will not ever be reflected in my model, and if the database schema is not exactly what it should be, EF will never notice, and I will only get weird exceptions, right?

How to be sure that when I modify a migration class, I do not cause inconsistencies? I assume I can only do two things: first, add new database objects which EF doesn't care about, second, change EF-generated migration code in a way that it ends up with the same schema (for example, if EF generates a `drop column` and an `add column`, I can change that to a `rename column`), and the `Down()` and `Up()` methods have to be consistent, is that all? For example, can I ever change the schema that EF cares about?

Comment: I have noticed that editing the generated code migrations doesn't actually take effect when I push them to the database. Perhaps I'm doing something incorrect, but this is just my experience.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*NOTE: I'll call "added-migration" to every migration created with `Add-Migration`, or automatically created by automatic migrations*

*NOTE: when I say "state of DbContext" I mean the definition of the model done in code first, i.e. the entities, their properties, relations and all other configuration*

*NOTE: "known by the DbContext" means all kind of database objects which the DbContext is aware of, like tables or views mapped to entities. There are a lot of other things in the DB that the DbContext is not aware of, including tables and views not mapped to DbContext entities*

> I hope I understand the basic workflow. First I create a model, then I generate an initial migration, and I generate an SQL from that, OK. I update the model, I create a new migration from that, and a new SQL from that, OK.

Of course, and you can change the DB schema from one added-migration to other added-migration, no matter if it's an upgrade or downgrade, or how many added-migrations are in between. I.e. you can specify source and target migrations.

> Am I correct in assuming that this is a one-way only workflow?

If this means that you can only apply migrations from code to DB, yes, it's only from code to DB, and no the other way.

> If I change the migration class in a bad way, it will not ever be reflected in my model,

Why would you do so? Migrations have been created just for doing it flawlessly without making mistakes. Why doing it by hand? An added-migration includes the definition of the process to upgrade from the DbContext state of a previously added-migration to the current DbContext state. And the process to downgrade, i.e. to go back to the DbContext state of a previously added-migration. If you're not careful when modifying the migrations, you can break this.

> and if the database schema is not exactly what it should be, EF will never notice, and I will only get weird exceptions, right?

Nope! it has nothing to do with migrations. Independently of migrations, when a DbContext is instanced, the model is created in memory, and checked against the DB schema. If it doesn't match, you'll get an exception. But this has nothing to do with migrations.

You usually modify your model, add a migration, and apply the migration to the DB, so that the DbContext and the DB schema are synchronized. Other option is to modify the DB and use a T4 template to reverse engineer the DB and obtain a DbContext from the DB schema. The question is that both must be synched, but it doesn't matter how you do it.

> How to be sure that when I modify a migration class, I do not cause inconsistencies?  I assume I can only do two things: first, add new database objects which EF doesn't care about, second, change EF-generated migration code in a way that it ends up with the same schema (for example, if EF generates a drop column and an add column, I can change that to a rename column), and the Down() and Up() methods have to be consistent, is that all? For example, can I ever change the schema that EF cares about?

Don't mix up DB schema, DbContext and migrations concepts.

As stated above, DB and DbContext must be synchronized.

An migrations are an easy way to achieve this synchronization: you create the initial model and add the first added-migration. Then you create the DB. The DbContext and the DB schema are perfectly synchronized. What would happen if you modified the migration in a way that the DB schema changed and didn't match the DbContext? Your DbContext and your DB schema would be different, and an exception would be thrown when instancing the DbContext.

**But then, why is there a migrations table on the DB?**

When you apply a migration to the DB, the schema of the DB is updated, and an **snapshot** of the current schema (more precisely, of the part of the schema "known" by the DbContext, not of the whole DB Schema) is taken, and stored in the `Model` column of `__MigrationHistory` table in the database.

Migrations knows how to change the DB schema from a "source" added-migration to a "target" added-migration. The migration history table is used to verify that the DB schema is consistent with the last applied migration. I.e. before applying a new migration, migrations verifies that he current DB schema matches the schema when the last  migration was applied by using the **snapshot** stored in the migrations table. If it doesn't match, the process will fail. If it matches, the migration will safely apply the changes from the "source" added-migration to the "target" added-migration, and store the **snapshot** of the resulting schema.

**So, how can you break things?**

- by modifying the migration code in a way that makes it inconsistent with the DbContext changes (for example, adding a new column in the migrations, and not adding it in the DbContext entity).
- by modifying the DB in a way that makes the DB schema different to the snapshot taken when applying the last migration (so, when you want to apply a new migration, the real schema and the snapshot will not match, and the process will fail)

**What can be done safely?**

Anything that doesn't change the schema of the DB "known" by the DbContext, i.e:

- adding objects (even tables) that are not "known" by the DbContext defined in the code (and of course triggers, stored procedures, views...)
- adding or removing data (rows from the tables), like populating master tables
- doing any other thing that doesn't modify the schema (modify security, configuration, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! You know, migrations generated a big C# file without any warning comments and that made me wonder. So now I know it is C# because I am allowed to tweak it a little, as long as the schema stays the same. Possibly dangerous, but also very flexible.

Comment: If you still think you need to make changes, you can test them: modify the migration, downgrade the db, update it with your modified migration, and run the application. If your change didn't break anything, it will work. If it did, you'll get the exception that tells you that the DB schema and the context don't match. Remember that when the DbContext is instanced for the first time its schema is compared to the DB schema.

Comment: Excellent answer, I quoted you in showing a colleague why he should not have made changes when the upgrade migration failed

Comment: One good reason to make modifications is to change an index to Descending. We query on Max(DateModified) because our caching mechanism needs it. I doubt EF will notice if an Index is ordered differently than expected when it goes to drop the index on a rollback or does some other comparison.

Comment: EF doesn't support indices in descending order. Apart from that, you're not going to see any performace change when getting a max or a min from an indexed column, regardless of it beign ascending or descending. You must have into account that an index is a highly optimized structure in which it's equally easy to get the first or the last element. The only case in which the performance can be modified is in the case of clustered indices which are usually those of the PK, because they affect the way in which the data is physically stored.

Comment: Because there are situations that migrations generator does not support such as when you have two relationships between the same tables where one is many:many and the other is one:optional. The migrations generator gets confused and generated cascading deletes for both relationships and the update-database command fails unless you specifically remove the cascading delete from the AddForeignKey call.